# simple express json parser

Tags: json, express, httprequest

trying to copy a simple example but still cannot parse json post request,
ideas?
looking in the borwser (firefox) network tab, I see the request with json params.
but the server log comes out empty.

client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">

        var man = {
          name:'name',
          fam:'familiy'
        };

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "http://localhost:8080/";
  xhttp.open("post", url, true);
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(man));

    </script>
    <title>Json Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Json Test
  </body>
</html>
```

server

```
//require the express nodejs module
var express = require('express'),
    //set an instance of exress
    app = express(),
    //require the body-parser nodejs module
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    //require the path nodejs module
    path = require("path");



//support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("done");
});


//Start listen on port
const port = 8080;
app.listen(port);
console.log("Node js listen on port " + port + "...");
```

Comment: "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well....
I guess I forgot these as well (working now)

```
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, **POST**, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting Content-Type header with your AJAX request. Please change to the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var man = {
      name:'name',
      fam:'familiy'
    };

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/";
    xhttp.open("post", url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(man));

  </script>
  <title>Json Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 Json Test
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: still not working actually, and the http request header is still: \n        Content-Typetext/html; charset=utf-8.    not sure why, but I did got it working in another page so

Comment: what does it mean when you say got working in another page? Do you see any cors errors?

Comment: @YanivPeretz FYI, you can use cors package if you want to enable CORS for cross domain AJAX requests. Please check https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors